# How do I copy the entire system root to an SD Card or USB Flash Drive?

Tags: 9.0-pie, file-management, terminal

I am trying to make a direct 1:1 clone of my Android 9 system. I have the device rooted and I am running 'Terminal Emulator' as super user. Now, if I am in the root directory (IE: ":/ #") and I feed it a "cp" command like this "cp / /storage/external_sd" I get an error saying "skipped dir 'storage/external_sd//' Cross Device link".

Note, I cannot use 'ADB' because my Android device is a USB host only and I'd need to reverse engineer the circuit board to find the solder points to allow me to connect as a client so I'm trying to do it via the software on the device itself.

Reason I am trying to clone the system is because I am trying to find a particular splash logo which comes up when the device has power, but I'll need to reverse the files once I have them dumped to see which one contains it exactly.

Thanks.

Comment: NOTE: "cp -a -v / /storage/external_sd" has worked, but I am getting "Operation not permitted" errors on most files. I assume some simply cannot be copied so the best method would be trying to get 'ADB' to work and do a full image backup.

Comment: You can edit your question at any time. For adding new info you therefore don't have to use the comments...

Comment: If the logo is displayed at a very early stage it might be located in the bootloader (changeable via hboot/fastboot) or the system/kernel image. Then you won't find it in the file-system.

Comment: Do you have any reference links on how to edit the hboot/bootloader logo on power up?

Comment: Nothing useful in English just google for `splashscreen hboot` and `splashscreen fastboot`.

Comment: Note that by `cp`ing to `external_sd` will **NOT** get you an "exact clone" – but a broken copy, as all permissions will be lost. `external_sd` uses a FAT style file system which doesn't support much POSIX. So you'd better use something that can take care of that, like: `tar czf /storage/<disk>/system.tar.gz /`. Further, as you see "operation not permitted": are you sure you run as root?

Comment: As Izzy mentioned, simply copying using `cp` is no way a workable way for backup/restore. All you get are the contents of mounted filesystems including `/data`, `/system` and `/vendor` (if applicable). Also there are a number of (usually more than a dozen) kernel's virtual filesystems (like `/proc` and `/sys`) mounted in rootfs or in subdirectories like `/mnt` and `/storage`. Backing up volatile/virtual filesystems isn't needed and would certainly throw errors. Instead you should dump whole partitions if needed.

Comment: As Robert said, splash screen at very early boot stage is shown by bootloaders. Usually there's a dedicated raw partition (usually named `splash` or something similar) to hold the image file(s) in very specific format which is not always editable. After kernel and `init` are loaded during boot process, a boot animation from `/system/media/` is displayed until zygote and apps are up. Usually OEMs replace the stock boot animation with their own.

Comment: Correct, I'm trying to replace the bootloader image. Not the boot animation after the kernel and `init` are called. I ran the command `df` but unfortunately this only shows mounted partitions and even so, I don't see anything named **splash** (or anything similar).

Comment: @t0rxe `df` is meant to show mounted filesystems. For all other partitions in your flash storage (e.g. eMMC or UMS) you need to look at your partition table using some partitioning tool. Some basic concepts about partitions and filesystems on Android devices: [Android Device Partitions and Filesystems](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-android-device-partitions-basic-t3586565)

Comment: Okay, I managed to hack it out and get a custom bootloader image in (more info: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224916/change-android-bootloader-splash-screen-image)